# subprocess.Popen - redirect stdin again

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Let's assume there's a program named 'ABC', which reads 4 integers from stdin and does something with them.

Recently, I leanred that we can use pipeline to feed the inputs to ABC, like following :

```
# send.py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ABC'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
print >>p.stdin, '1 2 3 4'
```

My question is : Can we redirect stdin again after calling `subprocess.Popen`?? For example,

```
# send.py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ABC'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
print >>p.stdin, '1 2 3'

(Redirect p.stdin to terminal's stdin)
```

, so that we can input 4th integer to ABC by typing on the terminal.

Comment: You want `send.py` to read from stdin and then write to `ABC`'s stdin?  Yes, absolutely you can do that.  And it's not called "redirection" in this case -- every program has its own stdin.  Use `input()` or `sys.stdin.read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection occurs before `ABC` is executed e.g., (on Unix) after the `fork()` but before `execv()` ([look at `dup2()` calls](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530437/23044)). It is too late to use the same OS level mechanism for the redirection after `Popen()` returns but you could emulate it manually.

To *"redirect `p.stdin` to terminal's stdin"* while the process is running, call `shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin, p.stdin)`. There could be buffering issues and the child process may read outside its standard input e.g., directly from the tty. See [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

You probably want something like [`pexpect`'s `.interact()`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.interact) (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect  # $ pip install pexpect

child = pexpect.spawnu('ABC')
child.sendline('1 2 3')
child.interact(escape_character=None) # give control of the child to the user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the fourth integer up front, then send it in along with the other 3:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ABC'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
fourth_int = raw_input('Enter the 4th integer: ')
all_ints = '1 2 3 ' + fourth_int
p.communicate(input=all_ints)
```

Comment: there is no reason to ask for 4th integer before sending the other 3: `p.stdin.write('1 2 3\n'); fourth = raw_input('4th int: '); p.stdin.write(fourth); p.stdin.close()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - You are correct. Mine is one way to get the job done. It is not the only way.